# Python: How to handle UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, unicode

This is what I am seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/tools/executeJobs.py", line 86, in <module>
    owner = re.sub('^(AS[0-9]+ )', '', str(element[2]))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In the error line you already see the line in question. `str(array[0])` never failed me before. How to work around this? A quick and dirty solution is fine.

**Update:**

Element[2] comes from this binary .dat list: http://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/tests/data/… also avail here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite (The IP/ASN one at the bottom of the table)

Comment: Do you know the encoding / contents of the text?

Comment: is element[2] unicode?

Comment: Element[2] comes from this list: https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/tests/data/GeoIPASNum.dat also avail here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Answer (score 1):

\xe7 appears to be the circumflex c `ç` in latin1 encoding

so assuming you have a unicode string `u"\xe7".encode("latin1")` should give you the bytestring `"\xe7"`, you could also choose to encode it as "utf8" `u"\xe7".encode("utf8")` would give you the bytestring `"\xc3\xa7"` ... that may or may not fix your issues however. but it will definately give you a different error

for a quick and dirty solution

```
try:
    owner = re.sub('^(AS[0-9]+ )', '', element[2])
except TypeError as e:
    print "Weird:",element
```

Comment: Could I do `except ValueError as e: owner = element.encode("utf-8")` ? Should it say `e` instead of `element` there?

Comment: Tests failed with:   `File "/home/user/tools/repository/nvla/executeJobs.py", line 87, in <module>
    owner = re.sub('^(AS[0-9]+ )', '', element[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: oops ... do `except TypeError` instead of valueerror ... changing it in the answer now

Answer (score -3):

I've always used

```
s.replace(u'\xa0',' ')
```

In your case, it should look something like

```
s.replace(u'\xe7','whatever')
```

Comment: He did say quick and dirty. @Sir Ben Benji, I'd imagine there is a better, more all-encompassing solution out there that might be worth waiting for if you want to handle more than just this one character

Comment: Yes, but I have to say there is lots of input and there might be other `\xcodes` as well.